$(ax+by+cz)^2\le (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ -Prove using Complex numbers
$S_1: \; (ax+by+cz)^2 \le (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ - How to prove this inequality using complex numbers?

The thought of this question came from $(ax+by)^2\le(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$ this inequality. So far as I learned This inequality can be proved by using Algebra, Trigonometry, Co-ordinate geometry, Complex numbers, Vector algebra .. (probably many more ways).
Using complex numbers, as I had learned, $z=(a+bi)(x-yi)$ be a complex number (assumed)
from,  $Re(z)\le|z|$ inequality we get this $(ax+by)^2\le(a^2+b^2)(x^2+y^2)$,

For, the three termed inequality $S_1$, I thought about cube root of unity, let,
$Z_1=a\omega+b{\omega}^2+c, \; Z_2=x{\omega}^2+y\omega+z \; \; $ be two complex numbers,
$Z_1\cdot Z_2=\color{blue}{(ax+by+cz)}+(az+bx+cy)\omega+(ay+bz+cx)\omega^2; \; \; |Z_1|=(\color{blue}{a^2+b^2+c^2}-ab-bc-ca); \; \; |Z_2|=(\color{blue}{x^2+y^2+z^2}-xy-yz-zx)$
Upto here I was able to generate the necessary terms for the proof but some other terms were also generated. I could not understand what to do hereafter. I anm also not sure if I am moving in the right direction. Please help or give some suggestion along with some reference.

It is already proven that
$(pq+rs)^2 \leq (p^2+q^2)(r^2+s^2) \qquad \qquad …(1)$
for any real numbers $p, q, r, s$. Let us call this inequality $(1)$. Take arbitrary real numbers $a, b, c, x, y$ and $z$. Define $B=\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ and $Y=\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$. We have by $(1)$ that $(ax+BY)^2 \leq (a^2+B^2)(x^2+Y^2)$ which gives the following:
$\left(ax+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sqrt{y^2+z^2}\right)^2 \leq (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2) \qquad \qquad …(2)$
Again applying $(1)$, we get that $(by+cz)^2 \leq (b^2+c^2)(y^2+z^2)$ and so, we have that
$by+cz \leq \sqrt{b^2+c^2}\sqrt{y^2+z^2} \qquad \qquad …(3)$
Now combining $(2)$ and $(3)$, together we get that
$\left(ax+by+cz\right)^2 \leq (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$
which proves the desired inequality. So, you can take complex numbers $\alpha=a+i\sqrt{b^2+c^2}$ and $\beta=x-i\sqrt{y^2+z^2}$ and apply your computations used for $(1)$.
Edit: This is a very famous inequality known as Cauchy Schwarz inequality that has an extension to infinite dimension spaces too.

that's nice, could not see it. Helpful.

You should also say that this inequality is very very well known under the name "Cauchy-Schwarz" inequality...
